# One Wordpress loop seems to be affecting the other

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop to get most popular posts at the top of my index page like this:

```
<?php while ( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>
endwhile;
```

and then the main loop below it to list all of the blog posts like this:

```
<?php while ( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>
endwhile;
```

However both loops dont seem to be working together - in the main loop that is supposed to be grabbing all of the posts - it is not and is missing the first week of posts. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [wp_reset_postdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after first loop